# How to start view chart on last page

Tags: views, charts

I am using the Charts module and Google Charts API with Views. I want my view to display with the last page of the view showing on page load. How can this be accomplished? For more explanation of what I'm trying to do: I have a view displaying a line chart with historical data, but I want the view to load with the most recent data first and the pager to allow the user to go back (using previous button) to view data in the past.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with charts, but in views SORT you could try using the opposite.

Ex: Sort Descending instead of Ascending. (so it reverses the order).

Then all you would have to do is override the pager so it says previous instead of next. I found some documentation [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21pager.inc/function/theme_pager/6#comment-693).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sort desc puts the latest data on the left side of the chart so it reads historically from right to left and not left to right as is natural.

Comment: "*Not familiar with charts*" ??? What's stopping you to use the [Ask Question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button around here ... eg to "get started with its Views interface"? If you do, make sure it fits the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) around here.

Comment: `What's stopping you to use the Ask Question button` I haven't tried to use the module yet. I would like to implement it for a project, but I am leaning towards using D8 for that project, so looks like I will have to wait.

Comment: @NoSssweat : your comment above was too challenging to me ... have a look at the question with id=198246  ... So if you have a chance to get into charting in D8, make sure to look at it. And if you do: I'd appreciate your feedback, good or bad, about it ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens another module I did not know about, I will check it out some time, thx.

Comment: @NoSssweat : **some people** (like Drupal *developers*?) spend their time on learning about all the bits and bytes to code whatever from scratch (and keep themselves busy with that for a loooooong time) .... **others**  (like Drupal *site architects*?) just look around and hunt for hidden gems, and think about how to use those gems ...